# using directive with templated member functions

Tags: c++, templates, using

I want to derive from a class which contains templated member functions. In the derived class I want to add some more specializations for the member functions. But how can I make the already defined methods from the parent class visible. Normally I have to use `using`, but I can't find the correct syntax for templated methods. And how I can say I want to define more specialized methods in the derived class without overwrite the non specialized method of the base class.

As we write the year 2017 any modern c++ dialects are welcome.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyType1{};
class MyType2{};

class A
{
    public:
        template <typename T>
            void Do() {std::cout << "Default" << std::endl; }
};

template<>
void A::Do<MyType1>() { std::cout << "For MyType1" << std::endl; }

class B : public A
{
    public:
       using A::Do; ??? how to do this for templated members?


        // how to make it possible to write more specializations without
        // defining a new "default" one?
        template <typename T>
            void Do() {std::cout << "Default of B" << std::endl; }
};

template<>
void B::Do<MyType2> (){ std::cout << "For MyType2" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    A a;

    a.Do<int>();     // should give "Default"
    a.Do<MyType1>(); // should give "For MyType1"
    a.Do<MyType2>(); // should give "Default"
    std::cout << "-----------" << std::endl;

    B b;
    b.Do<int>();     // should give "Default"
    b.Do<MyType1>(); // should give "For MyType1"
    b.Do<MyType2>(); // should give "For MyType2"
}
```

Comment: You might replace `std::cout << "Default of B" << std::endl;` by `A::template Do<T>();`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's not get all caught up in C++17 when good old tag dispatch will help us out:

```
namespace detail{
   template<class...>
   struct tag{}; // for dispatch to overloads below
}

class A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void Do() {
        DoHelp(detail::tag<T>{});
    }
protected:
    template<class... U>
    void DoHelp(detail::tag<U...>)
    {
        std::cout << "Default" << std::endl;
    }

    void DoHelp(detail::tag<MyType1>)
    {
        std::cout << "For MyType1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void Do() {
        DoHelp(detail::tag<T>{});
    }
protected:
    using A::DoHelp;
    void DoHelp(detail::tag<MyType2>){
        std::cout << "For MyType2" << std::endl; 
    }      
};
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9LqkwBQXBHo7FeUy)

Output:

```
Default
For MyType1
Default
-----------
Default
For MyType1
For MyType2
```

You've seen that the `using` statement successfully introduces templated names, but unlike inheriting constructors, it does not actually create those member functions, which would force you to specialize `Do` for `A` which is not what you want.

So instead we define overloads for the types that we want to specialize in `A`, and separately define overloads for the types that we want to specialize in `B`. We must hide `A`'s `Do` function in `B` with our own unfortunately, because class `A` cannot dispatch to B's overloads (But `B` can dispatch to `A`'s. The `using` statement for `DoHelp` is so that `B` can see `A`'s overloads).

The `tag` as you see is simply an empty templated `struct`. We use it as a way to distinguish otherwise identical functions (`DoHelp`). Because we don't use the parameter, an optimizing compiler will not actually construct the object, so we shouldn't see any overhead there. If we do, it will be only 1 byte.

Answer (score -1):

By writing Do method in class B you are actually adding a new template member function that shadows A::Do and not adding A::Do specialisation. Also there is no need for "using A::Do;" statement.

Comment: What you say is only true for constructors. Otherwise `using` is a great way to expose otherwise hidden base class members (in fact there are certain hacks to expose otherwise `private` Base class members...). Ultimately I agree with you, though; OP doesn't need `using A::Do`, but I can see what they are trying to do with it.

Comment: "By writing Do method in class B you are actually adding a new template member function that shadows A::Do". Exactly that is the reason to ask for "using" for the template methods. Normally if hiding a base class method it can be made visible by `using Base::Method;'  So also the rest of the answer will not help. You simply tell me what I already found :-)

Comment: You can add specialization to the base class's Do method, simply by writing template<> void A::Do<MyType2> (). Since template member specialization must be written in the namespace scope you always need to specialize it as base class method, even though all of them will be still accessible in derived classes. But making a.Do<MyType2>(); give "Default" and b.Do<MyType2>(); give "For MyType2" is not really possible without adding a new member function template. Because you can not have more than one template specialization with exact same parameters (and virtual template functions as well).